# Predicates of apparent temperature

Tags: verbs, adjectives

Predicates of apparent temperature like *cool*, *warm*, *hot*, *cold*, etc., can express both states of things or people (1b) and (more generally) the state of the weather (1b).

> (1a) It is now finally cool, this soup
>
> (1b) It is now finally cool in Miami

I was wondering if their verbal alternants also exhibit this ambiguity. Is it possible to have both (2a) and (2b)? My apprehension concerns the status of their transitive versions: (2a) seems to readily admit (3a) but (3b), whose source is presumably (2b), sounds weird to me.

> (2a) The soup is cooling (down)
>
> (2b) It is cooling (down) in Miami
>
> (3a) The chef is cooling it (down), the soup
>
> (3b) The scientists are cooling it (down) in Miami (by seeding the clouds)

Comment: We _never_ speak of 'cooling up'. The weather cools down after being too hot (and warms up after being too cold). Cooked food cools down.

Comment: The thermometer scale is based on vertical increase of a liquid in a tube due to temperature; hence _warmer_ means _higher_, like any numeric scale -- 100 is higher than 50.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for the clarification. Just edited my question.

Comment: I don't see any ambiguity. A hot object or substance cools down, and we say that 'it' (the weather) is cooler today. You are right that (3b) doesn't sound quite right, because we can't usually control the weather. Seeding the clouds to encourage rainfall is (at least in my experience) unusual enough to be described as 'attempting to lower the temperature' or similar, rather than a casual reference to 'cooling it down'.

Comment: "The scientists are cooling margueritas in Miami" is fine. And "Scientists with big air conditioners are cooling Miami" is fine. But "The scientists are cooling it in Miami" depends on what the antecedent of "it" is. "Cooling it" without an antecedent sounds like it means "chilling out". Maybe you're confused because "It" in a construction like "It is raining"/"It is cool" doesn't really have an antecedent, it's a dummy pronoun, so you can't rearrange it into the passive.

Comment: If this is in any way related to (1a) It is now finally cool, this soup or (1b) It is now finally cool in Miami, then why does it belong here in ELU, rather than somewhere like English Language Learners?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the "it" in (1b) and (2b) does not refer to anything anaphorically; it's the dummy "it" used as a subject in impersonal constructions. As such, it makes little sense to turn it into an object, as in (3b).

The usage of "it" in (1a) and (2a) also has no referent, but it's being used differently, as part of a nonstandard, or at least quite awkward, extraposition construction. Nothing prevents this construction from occurring in the object of a verb, as in (3a).